# In which programming language elementary OS terminal is written?

Tags: pantheon-terminal, programming

I just saw a similar question in https://askubuntu.com/ and got a doubt that in which programming language elementary OS terminal is written?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The terminal in elementary OS is written in [Vala](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vala_%28programming_language%29).

You can see information about Pantheon Terminal and even read the source code on [its Launchpad page.](https://launchpad.net/pantheon-terminal)